# Utilizar 2 eventos onChange con React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

Tengo un CRUD con una Api rest, para mandar datos uso una función `handleChange` con `onChange`, y quiero usar un datepicker que también utilice `onChange`.

```
const [tareaSeleccionada, setTareaSeleccionada] = useState({fecha: ""});


const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date);

const handleChange = (e) => {
const { name, value } = e.target;
setTareaSeleccionada((prevState) => ({
...prevState,
[name]: value,
}));
console.log(tareaSeleccionada);};
```

¿Cómo llamo a ambos eventos para que agarre la nueva fecha y lo mande a la api en react?

```
<DatePicker 
label="Fecha"
name="fecha"
format="dd/MM/yyyy"
value={selectedDate}
onChange={handleDateChange ; handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: ¿Para mandar los datos `onChange`? ¿Por qué no usar `onSubmit` en el formulario y lees tus variables de estado al momento de enviar la forma? No veo el problema. Lectura recomendada: [Formularios en React](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
const [tareaSeleccionada, setTareaSeleccionada] = useState({fecha: ""});


const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());

const handleChange = (e) => {
   const { name, value } = e.target;
   setSelectedDate(value);
   setTareaSeleccionada({
     fecha: value
   })
   console.log(tareaSeleccionada);
};
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica el funcionamiento del código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.